# Is it acceptable to include a scan of comic book page?

Tags: discussion, copyright, images

In a question I asked I would like to show the relevant page in the comic book. Is this allowed, and if so what citation should I use? I have it scanned in a jpeg format.

Comment: Considering [one of our top users](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765/thaddeus-howze) is famous for [answers like this one with several images of comic book pages](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86834/why-does-captain-america-need-to-exercise/86838#86838), you're probably fine as long as it's obvious what comic books they're from.

Comment: Just cite what book and issue it's from, and try to crop the scan down to the relevant panels if possible.

Answer (score 12):

**I Am Not A Lawyer** but this seems like [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) to me.

In US law, that means there are four important factors to consider:

1. Purpose and character of the use
   In this case, it would most likely fall under "for nonprofit educational purposes".
2. Nature of the copyrighted work
   Not really an issue here; it's not something that ought to be in the public domain.
3. Amount and substantiality
   Just one page, not the whole book.
4. Effect upon work's value
   It's not likely to decrease the value of the original work; one could argue it would *increase*.

Other jurisdictions often have similar provisions to allow quoting.

---

On this stack, we have a number of questions, like [one about covers of comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108546/19561), so quoting a page is nothing unusual.

In general, if you would have a hard time asking your question without it, it's probably okay to add it.