# Can I post pictures from the artwork (manga, manhua etc), when answering questions with #story-identification tag?

Tags: discussion, spoilers, policy, copyright

When people ask to help them identify the story, they might not need any of that. But people who never read the story or remember it too vaguely usually find it difficult to understand the thought process on how those (usually mismatched ) brief descriptions could correspond to the actual show. And during those times, it's way better to show it once, rather than try to explain. And then the question arises: is it legal?

Comment: Same question regarding uploading scans of physical comics here (though for a question) but the answer should still apply : https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8045/uploading-scan-of-comic-book-page

Comment: @fez - Yes, basically this question is a [dupe](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8045/uploading-scan-of-comic-book-page). 'Fair Use' applies here and it's certainly best practice to include a photo, a cover scan or anything else that may help OP to identify that this is the thing that they're after, especially if they can't access their own copy.

Comment: I voted for the dupe since we've already discussed sharing scanned comic book pages, which are much the same. As an additional note, for manga posted online, while we allow for a reasonable excerpt, even if the source is not legal, we do restrict providing a link to such sites.